# e325 attention warning on git branch merge

Tags: git, bitbucket, branching-and-merging

I tried merging a branch A into branch B, and I get this warning:

```
e325 attention merge made by recursive strategy
```

and my git-bash sort of hanged and I had to the bash window.

Does that affect my merging operation?

Comment: Can you show the command you entered, together with the complete git output?

Comment: `git checkout B`
`git merge A`